# how to enable admin console in jboss

Tags: jboss

when i start jboss, it return this:

```
    Calling "D:\Servers\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
"JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: D:\Servers\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

  JAVA: D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java

  JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

===============================================================================

12:35:34,229 INFORMAZIONI [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
12:35:35,009 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
12:35:35,047 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
12:35:36,728 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
12:35:36,729 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
12:35:36,738 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
12:35:36,743 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
12:35:36,760 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
12:35:36,762 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
12:35:36,780 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
12:35:36,781 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
12:35:36,794 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-14) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
12:35:36,799 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
12:35:36,812 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
12:35:36,818 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
12:35:36,835 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
12:35:36,841 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
12:35:36,852 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-16) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
12:35:36,858 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-16) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
12:35:37,010 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-13) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080
12:35:37,340 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
12:35:38,025 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
12:35:38,223 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory D:\Servers\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
12:35:38,229 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-16) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:4447
12:35:38,229 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
12:35:38,233 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-14) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: Address already in use: bind /127.0.0.1:9990
    at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.HttpManagementService.start(HttpManagementService.java:210) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:144)
    at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerImpl.<init>(HttpServerImpl.java:54)
    at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.DefaultHttpServerProvider.createHttpServer(DefaultHttpServerProvider.java:38)
    at org.jboss.com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create(HttpServer.java:147)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.ManagementHttpServer.create(ManagementHttpServer.java:145) [jboss-as-domain-http-interface-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.HttpManagementService.start(HttpManagementService.java:177) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more

12:35:38,459 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: Address already in use: bind /127.0.0.1:9990

12:35:38,502 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015954: Admin console is not enabled
12:35:38,503 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 4573ms - Started 131 of 208 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 74 services are passive or on-demand)
```

i tried to surf on web, but nothing work...
the page localhost:8080 returns 404 error.

how can i enable the console?

**edit**

the port is used by another process (thx to ozOli) 
the process is the jdk!
i terminate it and then, when i start jboss, it returns:

```
Calling "D:\Servers\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
"JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: D:\Servers\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

  JAVA: D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java

  JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

===============================================================================

17:38:29,149 INFORMAZIONI [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
17:38:29,289 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
17:38:29,320 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
17:38:29,825 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
17:38:29,825 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
17:38:29,834 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
17:38:29,839 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
17:38:29,853 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
17:38:29,859 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
17:38:29,870 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
17:38:29,871 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
17:38:29,875 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
17:38:29,876 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
17:38:29,884 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
17:38:29,892 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
17:38:29,908 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
17:38:29,926 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
17:38:29,948 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
17:38:29,970 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
17:38:30,050 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-3) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080
17:38:30,075 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
17:38:30,243 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-14) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory D:\Servers\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
17:38:30,243 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:4447
17:38:30,243 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
17:38:30,246 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015014: Re-attempting failed deployment MyWheelEE-war.war
17:38:30,249 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-12) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: Address already in use: bind /127.0.0.1:9990
    at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.HttpManagementService.start(HttpManagementService.java:210) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:144)
    at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerImpl.<init>(HttpServerImpl.java:54)
    at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.DefaultHttpServerProvider.createHttpServer(DefaultHttpServerProvider.java:38)
    at org.jboss.com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create(HttpServer.java:147)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.ManagementHttpServer.create(ManagementHttpServer.java:145) [jboss-as-domain-http-interface-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.HttpManagementService.start(HttpManagementService.java:177) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more

17:38:30,316 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
17:38:30,528 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: Address already in use: bind /127.0.0.1:9990

17:38:30,556 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "MyWheelEE-war.war"
17:38:31,118 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-10) Class Path entry lib/eclipselink.jar in "/D:/Servers/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/MyWheelEE-war.war/WEB-INF/lib/MyWheelEEJavaLibrary.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
17:38:31,119 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-10) Class Path entry lib/javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar in "/D:/Servers/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/MyWheelEE-war.war/WEB-INF/lib/MyWheelEEJavaLibrary.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
17:38:31,120 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-10) Class Path entry lib/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd.jar in "/D:/Servers/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/MyWheelEE-war.war/WEB-INF/lib/MyWheelEEJavaLibrary.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
17:38:31,121 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-10) Class Path entry lib/javaee-api-6.0.jar in "/D:/Servers/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/MyWheelEE-war.war/WEB-INF/lib/MyWheelEEJavaLibrary.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
17:38:31,165 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-9) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for MyWheelEE-warPU
17:38:31,168 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-9) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for MyWheelEEJavaLibraryPU
17:38:31,185 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.MyWheelEE-war.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.MyWheelEE-war.war".main: Failed to load module: deployment.MyWheelEE-war.war:main
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:91) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: Module org.eclipse.persistence:main is not found in local module loader @4e3e95e6 (roots: D:\Servers\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules)
    at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.findModule(LocalModuleLoader.java:126)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModuleLocal(ModuleLoader.java:275)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadModule(ModuleLoader.java:222)
    at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.preloadModule(LocalModuleLoader.java:94)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:841)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1181)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1207)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:208)
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more

17:38:31,193 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015954: Admin console is not enabled
17:38:31,193 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 2308ms - Started 138 of 218 services (3 services failed or missing dependencies, 76 services are passive or on-demand)
17:38:31,394 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "MyWheelEE-war.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.MyWheelEE-war.war\".main" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service.\"deployment.MyWheelEE-war.war\".main: Failed to load module: deployment.MyWheelEE-war.war:main"}}
17:38:31,419 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment MyWheelEE-war.war in 28ms
17:38:31,419 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.module.service."deployment.MyWheelEE-war.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.MyWheelEE-war.war".main: Failed to load module: deployment.MyWheelEE-war.war:main

17:38:31,419 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.MyWheelEE-war.war\".main" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service.\"deployment.MyWheelEE-war.war\".main: Failed to load module: deployment.MyWheelEE-war.war:main"}}}}
```

Comment: #FIXED some NVIDIA's process was using 9990 port;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## FIXED some NVIDIA's process was using 9990 port;)

Answer (score 5):

The admin console is most probably disabled.  To enable it using the CLI you can use this command:

```
/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface/:write-attribute(name=console-enabled,value=true)
```

Comment: the seems to say the change can't be done with the server running. try stopping it and editing the standalone XML manually.

Comment: The exception: Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind means that another process has used that port and address. Look for all processes using 8080 and terminate them. Then restart the server.

Comment: the port used was 9990 not 8080 ;)